# C# List remove multiple items

Tags: c#, list

If I have a List in C# Containing following elements:

```
Fish
Fish
Food
Stick
Fish
```

And I use `List<string>.Remove("Fish")` is it going to remove every fish element or just one of them?

Comment: Possibly unrelated to what you need but if you want to avoid any duplicates being entered in the first place, you can look at other collection types such as [HashSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Lists.

Comment: if you want to have distinct values in your list you can just use .Distinct()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the List.

It Removes the first but you can use `RemoveAll` Linq Extension Method:

```
List.RemoveAll(x=> x == "Fish");
```

Comment: @user3185569 why 15min?

Comment: @MichaelMao Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @SirRufo Thank you. I don't know that